# What do I do if a new question was migrated in review queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

[image: The question]

While reviewing *[First questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review)* (review queue), I saw the above question. I wasn't sure how to deal with it, because it was migrated. I'm not sure if this is a bug either because it was a test review.

If I encounter another similar question, how should I deal with it?

Comment: Flag as off-topic to migrate to the correct site (Meta Stack Overflow, in this case).

Comment: “If I encounter another similar question, how should I deal with it?” - Since you are unsure, Skip the review, that’s always a correct choice.

Comment: yeah but skipping reviews doesn't increase my reviews number